# what's wrong with my create view in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I can't figure out what's wrong with my create view. I need the submit button to redirect me to my show view so I can see all the created tags.
Here are the routes to create a tag, to show the tag and then store the tag:

```
Route::get('/tags/create', ['uses' => 'TagController@create', 'as' => 'tags.create']); //  Allows you to create a new tag

Route::post('/postTags', ['uses' => 'TagController@store', 'as' => 'postTags']); //    Place where all the tags are stored

Route::get('/tag/show', ['uses' => 'TagController@show', 'as' => 'tags.show']); //  Shows you all the existing tags
```

Here is my tag controller:

```
public function create()
{
    $tag = new Tag();
    return view('tags.create', compact('tag'));
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $tag = new Tag;
    $tag->name = $request['name'];
    $tag->save();

    return redirect()->route("tags.show");
}
public function show()
{
    $tags = Tag::all();
    return view('tags.show', compact('tags'));
}
```

And my create view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>New Tag</h1>
<form method="POST" action="{{route("postTags")}}">

    {{csrf_field()}}

    <label for="name">Click here to edit the title of your post!</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="name" required/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="window.location='{{ route("tags.show") }}'"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is the mistake, you given `name="Name"`, the first letter is capital, and in function all are small

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
    ]);

    $tag = new Tag;
    $tag->name = $request['name'];
    $tag->save();

    return redirect()->route("tags.show");
}
```

also you are creating object in the above function without calling the constructor `$tag = new Tag;`, create it as `$tag = new Tag();`

Comment: Can't believe  I didn't see that. Thank you. Can you take a look on my edit form as well? it doesn't submit anything when I click the button